# How can I list open share connections with share name and client access on a Windows server?

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares

`net session` shows open share sessions.
`net share` shows available shares.

But how can I get the list of open sessions for each specific share?
I know that the GUI can list Shares, Session and Open Files but a GUI is not suitable for process automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Win32_ServerConnection class](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmipsess/win32-serverconnection) for this.

In Powershell you can get the list of sessions sorted by shares with:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_serverconnection -computername $computername  | Select username, computername, sharename | sort sharename
```

Ready function for you:

```
Function Get-ServerConnection {
Param (
$ComputerName = 'localhost',
$account = '') # if empty, it means all accounts

# Now get the connections from that account
if ($account = '' )
   {
   Get-WmiObject win32_serverconnection -computername $computername  | Select username, computername, sharename | ft -a
   }
else
   {Get-WmiObject win32_serverconnection -computername $computername | where username -match $account | select username,computername,sharename | sort username
   }
}

Get-ServerConnection
```

Comment: GREAT, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.